# Not Understanding EF DBContext Actions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, savechanges

Microsoft documentation ([1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state)) states:

> Modified entities are updated in the database and then become Unchanged when SaveChanges returns.

But when I do a SaveChanges on a DBContext, items that were in the Modified state before then are still in a Modified state after the call.

In fact when I try to manually change the items' state to Unchanged in the following loop, they are changed back to Modified at the end of each loop iteration:

```
foreach(DbEntityEntry Item in Context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    Item.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried `Context.Entry(Item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;` instead?

Comment: Are you checking the return value from `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: Why do you need to check the state?  Assuming the records have actually been saved, the `state` is an internal representation, and not something you should really be touching.  Consider that a new DbContext should be created for each 'transaction', then the state will always be 'fresh'.

Comment: Could you provide us with more code please?

Comment: jcruz:  No difference using that notation.

Comment: David Tansey:  Yes.  It tells me that (for example) 2 items were saved.  If I run the SaveChanges twice in succession, the second execution also returns a 2.

Comment: Neil:  Because it doesn't seem that things are being set properly by SaveChanges, other things blow up downstream.